# Скачивание файла по протоколу ftp с Amazon S3

Tags: php, amazon-s3

Как скачать файл, который хранится в виде архива на амазоне, не на локальную машину, а прямо на мой сервер?

```
$url = "Backup/backup.zip"; 
$file_name = 'backup.zip'; 
$headers = [ 
'Content-Type' => 'application/zip',
'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; 
filename="'. $file_name .'"', 
]; 
return \Response::make(Storage::disk('s3')->get($url), 200, $headers);
```

вот так ошибки нет, файл скачивается на компьютер.

```
return \Response::make(Storage::disk('s3')->get(file_get_contents($url)), 200, $headers);
```

вот так - ошибка:

> file_get_contents(): failed to open stream: No such file or directory.

Если указать полный путь - тогда ошибка 403.

Comment: А в чем вопрос? Как скачать файл архива с FTP Амазона? В интернете написано как, да и в мане Амазона. Как поставить ftp-клиент на сервер? Тоже есть.

Comment: скачать на комп получается, но мне нужно скачать на ftp хоста, где лежит сайт, с которого я бекап делаю. Если добавляю file_get_contents - то получаю ошибку, что файла не существует

Comment: Вот, уже появились подробности. Проблема в file_get_contents. Может пароль не верный, может еще что-то. Добавьте код и конкретную ошибку в свой вопрос. И проблема уже получается не в Amazon скорее всего

Comment: $url = "Backup/backup.zip";
     $file_name = 'backup.zip';
  $headers = [
          'Content-Type'        => 'application/zip',            
          'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="'. $file_name .'"',
    ];
return \Response::make(Storage::disk('s3')->get(file_get_contents($url)), 200, $headers); - вот так с ошибкой

Comment: $url = "Backup/backup.zip";
     $file_name = 'backup.zip';
  $headers = [
          'Content-Type'        => 'application/zip',            
          'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="'. $file_name .'"',
    ];

 return \Response::make(Storage::disk('s3')->get($url), 200, $headers); - вот так ошибки нет, но скачивает на комп

Comment: Обновите вопрос. Так правильно.

Comment: 1. `Storage::disk('s3')->get(file_get_contents($url))` - фасад Storage в get() принимает путь к файлу в бакете (`Backup/backup.zip`), а вы зачем-то обернули в `file_get_contents`. Получается, `file_get_contents` пытается выкачать `Backup/backup.zip` - тут url составлен вообще неправильно. И полученные результаты (которых не будет) - подставить как параметр в `get()`. Зачем? 2. Какой полный путь хотите указать, и главное - зачем? `Storage::disk('s3')` - это бакет, работает с относительными путями. 3. Почему ftp? S3 имеет собственный протокол. Вообще не понятно, что вы пытаетесь сделать

Comment: 1. Хотите простой способ - используйте `$binaryData = file_get_contents('ftp://....')` - подставьте адрес и логин-пароль в соответствии со спецификацией URL. 2. Или научитесь работать с бакетами, и для этого ftp вообще не нужен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решился - настроил на амазоне прямую ссылку, и теперь скачиваю на фтп своего сервера